# Let f : R-> R be a differentiable function satisfying f ((x+y)/3) = (2+f(x) +f(y)) /3 for all real x and y and f'(2) =2 the range of f(|x|) is?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, relations

$f\left(\frac{x+y}{3}\right)=\frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3}$

find the range of $f(|x|)$ , please tell me the solution and weather we can do it using the limits : first principle. Im only a 12th grader so dont use any college level formulas(if they exist for this kind of thing)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See these posts on how to ask a good question: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question).  And, from the HELP center, I suggest you read through the pointers on ["asking questions"](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: Thank you , this question was actually my first one , i will keep these tips in mind next time i post a question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us find differentiable function $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that

$$ f\left( \frac{x+y}3 \right) = \frac{2+f(x)+f(y)}{3},\ f'(2) = 2.$$

First substitute $x \mapsto 3x$ and $y \mapsto 3y$ to get

$$3f(x+y) = 2 + f(3x)+f(3y)\tag{1}$$

Then, for $x = y = 0$ we get $3f(0) = 2 + f(0) + f(0)$ which implies that $f(0) = 2$.

Letting $y = 0$ gives $3f(x) =2+f(3x) +f(0)$ which implies that

$$f(3x) = 3f(x)-4\tag{2}$$

Now, use $(2)$ in $(1)$ to get $3f(x+y)= 2 + (3f(x)-4)+(3f(y)-4)$, i.e.

$$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)-2\tag{3}$$

Define $g(x) = f(x)-2$. If we subtract $2$ from both sides of equation $(3)$, we get $$g(x+y) = g(x)+g(y)\tag{4}$$

Equation $(4)$ is known as Cauchy functional equation and I strongly recommend that you read about it at [this beautiful MSE faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Since $f$ is differentiable, so is $g$. Therefore, $g(x) = ax$, for some constant $a\in\Bbb R$ (you can find why if you follow the link). Then, $f(x) = ax + 2$.

Finally, $f'(x) = a$ and condition $f'(2) = 2$ then implies that $a = 2$. Thus, $$f(x) = 2x+2$$

Hopefully, you can now finish the exercise yourself.

---

If you want to avoid mentioning Cauchy functional equation, you could use differentiability of $f$ more directly.

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}\\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=} \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(x)+f(y)-2-f(x)}{y}\\
&= \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(y)-2}{y} \tag{5}\\
\end{align}

In particular, $f'$ is constant, and thus $f(x) = ax+b$.

Returning to $(5)$ and using $f'(2) = 2$, we get

$$2 = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{ay + b - 2}{y} = a + \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{b - 2}{y}$$

Now, $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{b - 2}{y} = \pm\infty$, unless $b = 2$. It follows that $a = 2$.

Comment: @Harshit Pandey, you are welcome. You can show appreciation by upvoting/accepting answers (http://math.stackexchange.com/tour).